# Copy files excluding some folder in linux

Tags: linux, svn, rsync

I want to create script that copy my project and make it `zip` archive. I want to exclude all folder named `.svn` in all sub directories. Any suggestion?

Comment: Learn about the `find` utility.

Comment: Should you not ask it under serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use rsync's FILTER RULES for this:

Create an `.rsync-filter` file (in the origin directory) containing, e.g.

```
-.svn/
```

Now run rsync like an exalted copy:

```
rsync -aFF origin/ destination/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `rsync`. Although this is designed to synchronise directories across servers, it can also be used to copy directories on a single machine.

`rsync` has a `--exclude` option to exclude files and directories by pattern. See http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html for help and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `zip` utility on your project’s folder and use the `-r` option for recursive plus the `-x` option to exclude files / folders by pattern.

```
zip -r target-filename.zip source-folder -x \*exclude-pattern\*
```

`exclude-pattern` in your case would be .svn

See also `man zip`

Comment: this us not working for all sub directory, works only for specific dir